# Annotation-based null analysis - warning appears only with array parameter

Tags: java, eclipse, annotations, nullable, eclipse-jdt

I am getting the following (confusing) warning when using annotation-based null analysis where an array is involved:

> `Null type safety (type annotations): The expression of type 'int[]' needs unchecked conversion to conform to 'int @Nullable[]'`

This occurs when I pass an unannotated `int[]` to an `int @Nullable[]` parameter.

This is surprising. Normally it is only a problem if you take a nullable value and try to pass it to a nonnull parameter, but I am doing the opposite - taking a known non-null (though not annotated) array and passing it to a method (`Arrays.equals`) which does accept nulls.

Also it does not seem to be a problem with non-array objects. Normally a variable or return of (unannotated, non-array) type `T` can be assigned to a `@Nullable T`.

So my question is **why does this change when `T` is an array type**?

---

My class is a hashable/equality-comparable proxy for a native class that uses an `int[]` (taken from a C++ function) as a unique identifier. My package uses annotation-based null analysis and the 3rd-party package (with the native class) does not.

Here's a cut-down version that shows the problem:

**TagKey.java:**

```
package example;

import java.util.Arrays;

import org.eclipse.jdt.annotation.NonNull;
import org.eclipse.jdt.annotation.Nullable;

import other.Tag;

import com.google.common.collect.Interner;
import com.google.common.collect.Interners;

public class TagKey {

    private TagKey(Tag tag) {
        this.tag = tag;
    }

    public static TagKey forTag(Tag tag) {
        TagKey candidateKey = new TagKey(tag);
        return INTERNER.intern(candidateKey);
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Arrays.hashCode(this.tag.getUniqueIdentifier());
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(@Nullable Object obj) {
        if (this == obj) {
            return true;
        } else if (obj == null) {
            return false;
        } else if (getClass() != obj.getClass()) {
            return false;
        } else {
            return ((TagKey) obj).hasMatchingIdentifier(this.tag.getUniqueIdentifier()); // Warning appears here
        }
    }

    public boolean hasMatchingIdentifier(int @Nullable[] id) {
        return Arrays.equals(this.tag.getUniqueIdentifier(), id);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("null") // Guava cannot use type parameter annotations due to backward compatibility with Java 6
    private static final Interner<TagKey> INTERNER = Interners.newWeakInterner();

    private final Tag tag;

}
```

**package-info.java:**

```
/**
 * @author finnw
 *
 */
@org.eclipse.jdt.annotation.NonNullByDefault
package example;
```

**Tag.java:** (partial)

```
package other;

public class Tag {
    public native int[] getUniqueIdentifier(); // Currently returns a fresh array on each call, but may change in the near future to reuse a single array
}
```

---

### The workaround I am currently using:

```
    public boolean hasMatchingIdentifier(@Nullable Object id) {
        return id instanceof int[] &&
               Arrays.equals(this.tag.getUniqueIdentifier(), (int[])id);
    }
```

I would prefer to avoid these approaches:

- Adding `@SuppressWarnings("null")` to `TagKey` or its `equals` method (The production version is somewhat more complex and has a high risk of embarrassing NPEs.)

---

Notes:

- My JDT version is 3.10.0.v20140606-1215
- Earlier I made the mistake of declaring `@Nullable int[] id`. Surprisingly there was no warning message for this, even though it implies that the primitive `int` elements may be `null` which is clearly wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this method:

```
@SuppressWarnings("null")
public static int @Nullable[] getUniqueIdentifier(Tag tag) {
    return tag.getUniqueIdentifier();
}
```

then:

```
return ((TagKey) obj).hasMatchingIdentifier(getUniqueIdentifier(this.tag));
```

This is why I'm ignoring the "unchecked conversion from non-annotated" warning until nullity profiles are supported, you get stuck either suppressing null warnings everywhere (which defeats the point) or making annotated wrapper methods for every library.

Comment: Thanks, but I don't really want to do this as I am not sure it is an improvement over `hasMatchingIdentifier(@Nullable Object)`. Do you know why it behaves differently for arrays vs. non-array objects?

Comment: +1 anyway as I think you are right that ABNA is not mature enough yet for use on production code. But I wonder who will volunteer to create nullity profiles for the whole of the JRE.

Comment: Nullity profies, aka external annotations, will be supported in Eclipse Mars (4.5). Nobody uses the entire API of the JRE - adding just a few external annotations will typically go a long way towards a fully null-checked project.

Answer (score 0):

Any array being checked by Arrays.equals can handle nulls. You were right before to say @Nullable int[] id because @Nullable doesn't define that the items in the array are nullable, it defines that the parameter - the object reference - can be null. Arrays.equals(null, null) returns true.

```
private int[] a = null;
```

is perfectly reasonable code. So what you're checking for is that the array references match, which is true if all elements match each other, or if both references are null. If a variable is declared as int[], its internal members cannot, by definition, be null. That is, the code above is legal, this is not:

```
a[0] = null;
```

It'd be different of course if it was defined as Integer[], but it's not.

Comment: I don't think this is rignt - http://types.cs.washington.edu/jsr308/specification/java-annotation-design.html#array-syntax